# Not safe to print in signal handler?

Tags: c++, linux, signals, fork, handler

**That question didn't show an answer to my problem but yes it answered 1**

I read that doing the following isn't safe in C++:

```
int main() {
    signal(SIGTSTP, ctrlZHandler) == SIG_ERR
}

void ctrlZHandler(int sig_num) {
    std::cout << "got ctrl-Z" << std::endl;//THIS ISN'T SAFE!
    route_signal(sig_num);
}
```

1. why this isn't correct/safe?
2. In case I want to fix it, is it helpful if I remove the printing of "got ctrl-Z" inside route_signal function?

Comment: @SuperStormer what about my suggestion will it fix it?

Comment: That question didn't show an answer to my problem but yes it answered 1